# Electron wave function question?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

In interpretations of Quantum Mechanics that are Psi Ontic, in which the wave function is REAL ( Objective collapse theories, MWI, ect), does the wave function still physically spread to infinity? I know it does mathematically, but does it physically?

Comment: Sticking a question mark at the end of a phrase doesn't make it a question. You could make the title much more specific and this will help other users.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of QM effects extend to infinity. Its a linear theory, which means that the solutions can extend indefinitely (and have to in order to keep the theory working). The probability density extent of one of the electrons your brain extends everywhere in the Universe. Its amplitude will be very small in most places to put it mildly, but without these huge areas of infinitesimal probability amplitude, the theory fails to have unitarity (i.e. probabilities adding to exactly 1) and fails.

My answer is for 'regular QM'. There is no difference between mathematically and physically in this case. If QM is correct (and lots of people think it is for some reason) then the wave function physically spreads to infinity.

Comment: Except of the absurdity of presuming that every time one moves one's hand infinity rearranges itself. All this confusion comes from assigning physical existence to mathematical models. At least in the probabilistic use of the mathematics it is extremely improbable that it will happen. much less anthropic.